# Angular Routing. Don't force login on saved changes in localhost project

Tags: angular, authentication, routes

Every time I make a change in my .scss and save, it forces a redirect to login module in my app. I simply want the changes to recompile on the server without having to login again to see the changes.

Another dev worked on the login routing and I'm not certain if this is forced behavior or default.

Is it possible to simply reload the current page on file updates? Without forcing a new login.

Angular 6

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking for hot module replacement?

I have not done this, but found an article on how to set it up here: https://medium.com/@kubal5003/angular-4-hot-module-reload-explained-e832ea616304

Or you can use a tool that already has it set up. I think the latest Visual Studio 2017 Angular templates provide this feature.

Another hack-y way (the way I do it) is to simply comment out the route guard for the login during development. The downside is that you have to remember to uncomment it before deploying to production. :-)